# XML transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to transform an xml file to another xml file using xslt.
The input file is as below:

```
<root type="object">
    <items type="array">
        <item type="object">
            <updated_at type="string">2017-05-20</updated_at>
            <external_id type="null"></external_id>
            <created_at type="string">2017-05-20</created_at>
            <embed_code type="string">ec111</embed_code>
            <status type="string">live</status>
            <content_type type="string">video</content_type>
            <name type="string"></name>
            <hosted_at type="null"></hosted_at>
        </item>
        <item type="object">
            <updated_at type="string">2017-05-19</updated_at>
            <external_id type="null"></external_id>
            <labels type="array">
                <item type="object">
                    <name type="string">lbl name 1</name>
                    <full_name type="string">full lbl name 1</full_name>
                    <id type="string">lbl1</id>
                    <parent_id type="string">parent_id_1</parent_id>
                </item>
            </labels>
            <created_at type="string">2017-05-20</created_at>
            <embed_code type="string">ec112</embed_code>
            <status type="string">live</status>
            <content_type type="string">video</content_type>
            <name type="string">test</name>
            <hosted_at type="null"></hosted_at>
        </item>
        <item type="object">
            <updated_at type="string">2017-05-19</updated_at>
            <external_id type="null"></external_id>
            <labels type="array">
                <item type="object">
                    <name type="string">lbl name 2</name>
                    <full_name type="string">full lbl name 2</full_name>
                    <id type="string">lbl2</id>
                    <parent_id type="string">parent_id_2</parent_id>
                </item>
                <item type="object">
                    <name type="string">lbl name 3</name>
                    <full_name type="string">full lbl name 3</full_name>
                    <id type="string">lbl3</id>
                    <parent_id type="string">parent_id_3</parent_id>
                </item>
            </labels>
            <created_at type="string">2017-05-20</created_at>
            <embed_code type="string">ec113</embed_code>
            <status type="string">live</status>
            <content_type type="string">video</content_type>
            <name type="string">testing</name>
            <hosted_at type="null"></hosted_at>
        </item>
    </items>
</root>
```

Need to transform the above xml to the below format:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<labels>
    <item>
        <embed_code>ec112</embed_code>
        <name>lbl name 1</name>
        <full_name>full lbl name 1</full_name>
        <id>lbl1</id>
        <parent_id>parent_id_1</parent_id>
    </item>
    <item>
        <embed_code>ec113</embed_code>
        <name>lbl name 2</name>
        <full_name>full lbl name 2</full_name>
        <id>lbl2</id>
        <parent_id>parent_id_2</parent_id>
    </item>
    <item>
        <embed_code>ec113</embed_code>
        <name>lbl name 3</name>
        <full_name>full lbl name 3</full_name>
        <id>lbl3</id>
        <parent_id>parent_id_3</parent_id>
    </item>
</labels>
```

The path root/items/item will have embed_code tag. And in the same path it may have labels node or may not have labels. labels may have one or more than one item.

Transformation rules are as follows:
1) Need to get Labels and their children
2) Remove all the attributes
3) Bring embed_code node into each labels/item node

Below is my code so far:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:a="item">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <labels>
            <xsl:for-each select="root/items/item">
            <xsl:variable name="eCode" select="embed_code"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="labels/*">
            <item>
                <embed_code>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$eCode"/>
                </embed_code>

                <xsl:for-each select="root/items/item/labels/item/*">

                </xsl:for-each>
            </item>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </labels>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*" />
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Unable to bring the child nodes of labels/item. please help me on this.

Thanks

Comment: Don't dump work assignments into Stack Overflow. Do your own work. When you have a question about the XSLT stylesheet you are currently writing, post your code and ask a specific question about it, and we are happy to help.

Comment: I have edited the post to include my xslt work so far. I want to bring the child nodes of labels/item.

Comment: That's better. Always include your code and the a problem description.

Answer (score 0):

You are unable to get to the child nodes of labels/item because you are using a wrong path in

```
<xsl:for-each select="root/items/item/labels/item/*">

</xsl:for-each>
```

There is no `root` under any `<item>`. It looks like you were trying to use an absolute path, which is also the wrong thing.

Use a relative path instead. `*` is enough to get all child elements because the `<xsl:for-each>` already moves your context node to the `<item>` in question. Compare:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:a="item">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <labels>
            <xsl:for-each select="root/items/item/labels/item">
                <item>
                    <embed_code>
                        <xsl:value-of select="../../embed_code"/>
                    </embed_code>

                    <xsl:for-each select="*">
                        <xsl:copy>
                            <xsl:value-of select="." />
                        </xsl:copy>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </item>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </labels>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Notes

- nesting `<xsl:for-each>` like you did is not really necessary, a single for-each does the same thing
- `<xsl:copy>` copies the current node to the output, you can use it if you want to keep the node name

Result of the above with your input:

```
<labels xmlns:a="item">
   <item>
      <embed_code>ec112</embed_code>
      <name>lbl name 1</name>
      <full_name>full lbl name 1</full_name>
      <id>lbl1</id>
      <parent_id>parent_id_1</parent_id>
   </item>
   <item>
      <embed_code>ec113</embed_code>
      <name>lbl name 2</name>
      <full_name>full lbl name 2</full_name>
      <id>lbl2</id>
      <parent_id>parent_id_2</parent_id>
   </item>
   <item>
      <embed_code>ec113</embed_code>
      <name>lbl name 3</name>
      <full_name>full lbl name 3</full_name>
      <id>lbl3</id>
      <parent_id>parent_id_3</parent_id>
   </item>
</labels>
```

Comment: What does the `xmlns:a="item"` part do?